# Change the Jazz ID for a Bluemix account

Tags: ibm-cloud, jazz, devops

Some time ago I started to use the Bluemix platform to develop PHP services that were used by a mobile application. After a while, I realized that it would be very useful to have a repository to which I can connect multiple Eclipse IDEs and work on the same application.
I already had a Jazz ID which was used for the work projects; I am talking about using Bluemix+Jazz for personal projects.

When I first connected the Bluemix ID with the Jazz ID, everything was well. But I realized that it might be a conflict of interest because I am using the same Jazz ID for both work and personal projects.

**My question is: Is there a way to use a new Jazz ID in Bluemix?** 
It seems that the connection between the two IDs cannot be changed from Bluemix, DevOps or Jazz.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Costin, thanks for your interest in IBM Bluemix and the IBM Bluemix DevOps Services. Like Lauren has said, you'll probably want two IBM IDs, one for your work email address and one for your personal. They ultimately can be associated with two Bluemix orgs, each associated with a different DevOps user.

You'll need to decide which Bluemix org you want each of your apps to live in; the corresponding user should own the app's Git repository. To move a Git repository, you can use either of these approaches:

1. Use the repository's "Download the contents of this branch as a zip file" button to download the contents. Then as the other user, create a repository and import the zip file.
2. Share the repository with the other user, fork as the new user to get a copy.

Once you have the code in the other user's repository, redeploy to that user's Bluemix org.

Once you have everything where you want it, delete the stuff (apps and repositories) that are not where you want them.

Comment: Thanks Bobby for the suggestion. Just a few other info which I should have mentioned earlier:
1. The Bluemix account is created with my personal email address because Bluemix is in no way used in the work project.
2. The Jazz ID is used in the work project.
3. It was best to avoid making the connection between my Bluemix account and the work Jazz id.

Comment: I can create a new Bluemix account because I have another email address. I was looking for any possibility to keep my current Bluemix account, but I will continue with a new one and it will be fine.
So, I will accept your answer because you suggested how to move the code from the "old" repository to the "new" repository.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a new IBM id that is linked to your personal e-mail address.  The IBM id could be used to sign in to Bluemix and DevOps Services.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
That is what I will do eventually, but generally, it's a pretty messy thing to do.
Trying to judge both options:
1. Make a change in the way IBM IDs get connected with Jazz IDs to avoid situations like mine in the future. (effort from IBM side, very easy for the user)
2. Make the user create a new IBM ID, create the applications and DB2 databases again, then connect with the new Jazz ID and continue the work from there (no effort from IBM, big effort on user side)

I must admit, my situation may not be very general, and not every user will encounter this.

Comment: Maybe a suggestion: Whenever the Jazz ID is linked with the IBM ID, there should be a warning saying: "Jazz ID cannot be modified later." This would make the user aware ahead of time about this situation.

PS: Lauren, if no one else will give a solution to this, I will accept your answer. Thanks.